# Python 2's webbrowser is not working in repl.it

Tags: python, google-chrome, python-webbrowser

I am using repl.it, and also the webbrowser module to open a link using `webbrowser.open("https://google.com/")`
But, my link doesn't work. Can you help me with this?

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://google.com/", 2)
```

Comment: And oh, I'm using python2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the answer like this:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(*website*)
```

Of course, replace * website * with the site and no need to write the 2.
Then tell me if it works.

And by the way, some online python processor like  [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com)  do not allow opening all websites.
 Instead, they only allow some specific websites.